# Returing results only when two dates don't match

Tags: date

I have a table `notes`.  With fields `service_date` and `create_date`.  I only want to see a result if the `service_date` is `>='01-JAN-2012` AND if the `service_date` and `create_date` do not match.

I have tried

```
select applicant_id, service_date, create_date
from notes
where service_date!=create_date
```

But I get results where those 2 dates match, so it isn't working.

I'm sorry, I am using Oracle

Comment: Might help if you mention the RDBMS you're using.  Given the date string format and column names, I would guess Oracle.

Comment: Sure those dates don't have a time component? 01-JAN-2012 09:00:00 does not equal 01-JAN-2012 09:01:00.

Comment: Yes, there is not a time component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
select applicant_id, service_date, create_date
  from notes
 where trunc(service_date) != trunc(create_date)
   and service_date >= to_date('01/01/2012', 'dd/mm/yyyy')
```

(Dates in oracle DB always have a time component - even if you don't display it)